# How did Gandhari know that seeing her son Duryodhana without eye bandage would make his body IRON?

Tags: mahabharata, gandhari

During the kurukhetra battle, one day *Gandhari* asked her son *Duryodhana* to come and meet her naked. *Durodhana* agreed and when he was on his way, *Krishna* stopped him and advised not to go naked infront of her mother, that would be a shameful act.

*Duryodhana* thought its a true advice and wrapped him with a Banana tree leaf. *Gandhari* removes her bandage and was surprised to see that her son was not completely naked as it was instructed to him.

Duryodhan's body turned into iron except the part which was covered by banana tree leaf and because of this, he was defeated in wrestling (mallyudha) against *Bhim*.

So the question is, how *Gandhari* knew that her eye sight/rays (when no bandage) had so much power that it could make a person's body turn into an iron?

Comment: After Karna's death, gandhari visited ved vyasa, he told her that she has power in her eyes, and she can give this power to any one of her son by eyes.

Comment: when did she go? I mean at which chapter, what made her to visit ved vyas rishi?

Comment: The above story of Gandhari blessing Duryodhan, is popular folklore. There are no shlokas to support the story. But we can still check this by reading online mahabharata translations on sacredtext site.

Comment: I have just found something here... https://www.facebook.com/MahabharatKiGalatiyan/posts/519043464875207

Comment: the power is not in eyes of Gandhari. She prepared some liquid (from ayurvedic knowledge)and applied on Duryodhana's body.

Comment: @estari LOlzzz and who prepared that for her. Where it is written in The MAHABHARAT.

Answer (score 3):

All our powers are a result of our unswerving spiritual practices. Gandhari's spiritual practice consisted of pativrata dharma (the way of a chaste wife) by way of forfeiting what her husband did not have (her husband DhrtarAshTra was blind). Since she withdrew her visual sense from the world, and turned it inwards, her visual faculty attained certain supernatural powers. She wanted to use this power to benefit her son. The way to shower visual power is to to physically see the target.

In general, practising a dharma or truth will give one power over that faculty. For e.g., if you practise speaking the truth alone and nothing but the truth for a few years, your speech will attain the power of making what you say come true. This is called vAk siddhi. The moment you go lax on speaking the truth, you will lose this power. And if you use it for evil, then also the power will be lost and one will have to suffer the consequences of inflicting pain on the universe.

Comment: What are you talking about man, totally irrelevant answer. It will bring loads of down votes for you.